# Manually invoking stream action in server sent event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

How do I send update notifications to clients using server sent event?

What I want to accomplish is that when a client ajax calls an action, the server then would send relevant data to all connecting clients through my stream action.

I'm trying to know if this would be possible without websockets or pub/subs.

Comment: You can use the [`ActionController::Live::SSE`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html) functionality of Rails

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, you're looking for a generalized approach, rather than specific code?

--

**SSE's**

[Server Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) are an HTML5 technology, meaning that if you do it correctly, it shouldn't matter whether you use Rails or another framework -- they should just work

One drawback to SSE's is they act very similar to Ajax long-polling, meaning they send constant "pings" / requests to your server, relaying back any response they find. And they'll still use the `pub/sub` pattern too

-

Simply, SSE's are when you have a Javascript ["event listener"](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp), which will listen to an ["endpoint"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) (URL). The endpoint, in the case of Rails, will be a `controller#action`, from which you can send the relevant `text/event-stream` updates, which is what [`ActionController::Live::SSE`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html) is there to do

--

**Setup**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :your_controller do
   collection do
      get :endpoint
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var source = new EventSource('your_controller/endpoint');
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ActionController::Base
   include ActionController::Live

   def endpoint
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
      sse = SSE.new(response.stream, retry: 300, event: "event-name")
      sse.write({ name: 'John'})
   ensure
      sse.close
   end
end
```

This will send the relevant updates for you every time